# difference between foo[i] and foo->at(i) with stl vector

Tags: c++, stl, vector

is there any reason why

foo = (bar->at(x))->at(y);

works but

foo = bar[x][y];

does not work, where bar is a vector of vectors (using the c++ stl)

the declaration is:

> std::vector< std::vector < Object * > * >

Comment: How is the vector declared, `std::vector<std::vector *>`? Your usage of `at` suggests pointers, or is it a typo? Otherwise, shouldn't it be bar.at(x).at(y)?

Comment: Just because C++ has pointers doesn't mean **every** variable in your program has to be one. Remove every single pointer from this, and it should work.

Comment: Looks like bar is a pointer to a container that constains pointers. But it would nice to have the actual type of 'bar'

Comment: Like I and others said below, you can't use `operator[]` on pointers without dereferencing them. (Either `bar->operator[]()` or `(*bar)[]`. Free funtions may be the second cleanest method. Cleanest is no pointers.

Comment: @GMan: Sure you can use [] on a pointer. It just doesn't do what the OP intended. ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is it a vector of vectors or a vector of pointers to vectors? Your code should work *as advertised*:

```
typedef std::vector<int> vec_int;
typedef std::vector<vec_int> multi_int;

multi_int m(10, vec_int(10));

m.at(2).at(2) = /* ... */;
m[2][1] = /* ... */;
```

But your code appears to have:

```
typedef std::vector<vec_int*> multi_int; // pointer!
multi_int* m; // more pointer!
```

If you have pointers, you'll need to dereference them first to use `operator[]`:

```
(*(*m)[2])[2] = /* ... */;
```

That that can be ugly. Maybe use references temporarily:

```
multi_int& mr = m;
(*mr[2])[2] = /* ... */;
```

Though that still has some ugly. Maybe free-functions are helpful:

```
template <typename T>
typename T::value_type& access_ptr(T* pContainer,
                                    unsigned pInner, unsigned pOuter)
{
    return (*(*pContainer)[pInner])[pOuter]);
}

access_ptr(m, 2, 2) = /* ... */
```

**Most preferable is to be rid of the pointers**, though. Pointers can leak and have all sorts of problems, like leaking when exceptions are thrown. If you *must* use pointers, use a [pointer container](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html) from boost for the inner vector, and store the actual object in a [smart pointer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm).

Also, your title is a bit misleading. The difference between `at` and `operator[]` is that `at` does range checks. Otherwise, they are the same.

Comment: I assumed `bar`was a `std::vector<std::vector<T> >*`, hence the `->at()`

Comment: It would need to be `std::vector<std::vector<T>* >*`, there are two `->` .

Comment: Oops yeah, I didn't see the other one. Charles is right, of course

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure you have a vector of vectors? If you did then

```
foo = bar[x][y];
```

would be like

```
foo = bar.at(x).at(y);
```

but without the range checking and exception behaviour of `at`.

If `bar->at(x)->at(y)` works, then this is likely to be somewhat equivalent to `(*(*bar)[x])[y]` and not `bar[x][y]` but must mean that `bar` isn't a vector of vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if bar is a pointer (as the first example suggests), you would need to rewrite your second example to:

```
(*(*foo)[x])[y]
```

Answer (score 1):

if bar is a pointer, you'd want to dereference it first:

```
(*bar)[x][y]
```

if its a pointer to a vector of vector pointers:

```
(*(*bar)[x])[y]
```

as [R Samuel Klatchko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060900/difference-between-fooi-and-foo-ati-with-stl-vector/2060917#2060917) and others mentioned

Answer (score 1):

It would seem you have a pointer to a vector of pointers to vectors ...

So if you want to do as you've tried you'd need

foo = (*((*bar)[x]))[Y];

Use a vector of vectors (ie std::vector< std::vector< datatype > > instead.

Edit:  Also worth noting that at does do some range checks so, provided you don't need those range checks, is slower than using operator[].

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you define "works" and "doesn't work". What happens when it "doesn't work"?
The main difference between the two is that `at` performs bounds-checking, which `operator[]` does not.

But in your case, the problem is that `bar` is **not** a vector of vectors. It seems to be a *pointer* to a vector of pointers to vectors. (Which in itself is a bad sign. It probably doesn't need to be a pointer. Is everything also dynamically allocated with `new`? Don't do that by default)

And that means that you're trying to invoke `operator[]` on a pointer, not a vector -- which is defined, but does something other than you expect. The code in your second case is effectively equivalent to `(*(bar+x))[y]` - and apart from going out of bounds yielding undefined behavior, the result would be a pointer to a vector of whatever type foo is, rather than an element of that vector.

Answer (score 0):

For

```
foo = (bar->at(x))->at(y);
```

to work `bar` would have to be a pointer and the vector it points to would have to contain pointers.

For

```
foo = bar[x][y];
```

to work, `bar` would have to be a `vector` (not a pointer) that contained vectors (not pointers).